# How to cancel auto reconnect mechanism in Paho Android Client when internet is not available?

Tags: android, mqtt, paho

We are using PahoAndroidClient and it works just fine. However we want to cancel auto reconnect mechanism for example after 10 failure tries when network connectivity is not available.

In this case, we want to close or disconnect the current MqttAndroidClient instance and later when user have access to the internet, we connect it again (we don't want to leave Mqtt service running, reconnecting and draining battery).

Now by invoking disconnect method on an instance of MqttAndroidClient which is still alive and trying to reconnect, nothing will happen (still trying to reconnect). In addition, if the next time when user have access to the internet, we create a new object and connect it to the server, the previous instance also can connect and it causes a duplicate connection issue on the server while two simultaneous client are connecting with a common clientId.

Comment: Would also be good if you can show, how you are trying to disconnect!

Comment: This sounds like a feature request that may be better discussed on the Paho mailing list

Comment: @LalitPoptani we use mqttAndroidClient.disconnect(). But if mqttAndroidClient is in reconnecting state, this won't stop reconnecting procedure. Finally if internet gets back, it connects! So we want to kill or stop the current instance and then create a new instance once internet is back.